# Gvim 8.1 on Windows 10 won't source $HOME\_vimrc

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows, vim8

I have a `$HOME\_vimrc` present, but it doesn't show up in the output of `:scriptnames`. And when I run `gvim -V`, it reports:

```
could not source "$HOME\_vimrc"
```

The only thing in my `$HOME\_vimrc` is the following line:

```
set packpath+=C:\Users\username\vimfiles
```

In case there was something wrong with that path, I also changed the entire contents of the `$HOME\_vimrc` file to this, with the same result:

```
set number
```

When I run `:echo $HOME` from gvim, it reports my Windows user profile directory `C:\Users\username`. I have a `$HOME\_gvimrc` which it reads fine. My vimfiles directory is at the default `$HOME\vimfiles` which it seems to read fine, because it's sourcing a color scheme from there.

Running `:version` shows the following entries:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
    [...]
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
    [...]
```

Running `:echo $MYVIMRC` outputs `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`.

I've tried running as both administrator and my Windows username.

Is there something I'm missing?

### Edit:

The output of `icacls _vimrc`:

```
C:\Users\username> icacls _vimrc
_vimrc NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
       BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
       DOMAIN\username:(I)(F)
```

That last entry, DOMAIN\username, is the login I'm using to run gVim.

Comment: What's the output of "icacls _vimrc"? This will display your permissions for the file.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Rob's suggestion is a good place to start (this could be a permissions error). Please [edit] your question as you provide new details

Comment: I've updated the question to include the output. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @RobMosher I can't read windows stuff there, so idk if that's right

Comment: The (F)s indicate ful read/write access for each of those users. But it looks like William found the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to define `$HOME` as a Windows environment variable.

Once I did that and restarted gVim, it read my `~\_vimrc` and also sourced my native Vim 8.1 packages correctly.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598312/vim-gvim-8-1-on-windows-10-wont-source-home-vimrc) at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Fallback to `$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH` or `$USERPROFILE` should usually take care of that... Do you not have those defined in your environment for some reason?

Comment: Ah, `$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH` is set to `M:\ `, which is a mapped network drive. `$USERPROFILE` is set to `C:\Users\username`. If it was using`$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH`, it would explain why it couldn't find my _vimrc, but then why does `:echo $HOME` show `C:\users\username`?

Comment: You might want to update your answer to reflect that. Yeah it's odd that `:echo $HOME` is showing the other path... Not sure why that would happen...

Comment: It may be that vim is setting `$HOME` itself somehow, or that it is coming from somewhere else. I would open up a windows terminal, and get the environment value `HOME` (I think the syntax on cmd is `%HOME%` or something)

Comment: `%HOME%` was not set in Windows. Once I set it in Windows, gVim started reading my `~\_vimrc`.

Comment: This line was in the $VIM\_vimrc: `let $HOME = $USERPROFILE` but I don't think that's relevant, because $HOME is needed before reading that file, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was trying to source my vimrc file within gvim/vim and my changes were not being applied in the session. I would have to reopen gvim/vim to see the changes. Adding the `$HOME` user environment variable: `C:\Users\<username>` resolved this.

For my setup I am using Windows 10 and vim/gvim 8.2.

Instead of using the user vimrc file: `$HOME\_vimrc` and user gvimrc file: `$HOME\_gvimrc` I used 2nd user vimrc file: `$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc` and 2nd user gvimrc file: `$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc`

These were the values prior to the addition of the windows user environment variable and did not change afterwards.

```
:echo $VIM = C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim
:echo $HOME = C:\Users\<username>
:echo $HOMEDRIVE = C:
:echo $HOMEPATH = \Users\<username>
:echo $MYVIMRC = C:\Users\<username>\vimfiles\vimrc
:echo $MYGVIMRC = C:\Users\<username>\vimfiles\gvimrc
```

Note: I did not have enough reputation to comment, but I still wanted to add this in case anyone else decides to use the 2nd user vimrc/gvimrc files instead.